# How to set the correct validation of the sharepoint columns

Tags: sharepoint

What formula could I use in SharePoint as when column `x` is `<< Yes >>`, the `Y` field is automatically set to `N / A`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Y as a calculated column
and set formula as

=IF([X]="Yes", [Value])